# How to separate my process with current app domain and create new domain for that process?

Tags: c#, multithreading, appdomain

I am working with heavy software and its already has many processes started in background. And now I introduced a new feature in that, but I want to use separate for all processes like if any current process has crashed then this process will not affect. So how can I differentiate with all processes? And even I want to use the separate app domain for this particular process. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A separate `AppDomain` is not a separate process. If an unhandled exception occurs in a separate `AppDomain`, the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) will be raised and then the application will terminate.

Comment: But if my one app domain crashes then parallel other app domain should work as it is. and how can i use 2 app domain in same process?

Comment: This might be helpful: [How do I create an application domain and run my application in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648411/how-do-i-create-an-application-domain-and-run-my-application-in-it)